# Filter repeated columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to see the same pid(or id from the person_info table) only once with the sql below. Adding "group by pid" in the end would work in MySQL but not in Oracle because I would have to have a group by for each after select. Distinct doesn't work here either because it returns unique combinations and not just pid. 
This is driving me crazy... Thanks in advance!

```
select pi.id                 pid,
   n.id                  nid,
   n.match_mode,
   n.match_method,
   n.match_gene_type,
   n.notification_status,
   pi.person_name,
   pi.id_card_no,
   pi.race
from notification n, person_info pi
where (n.src_data_id = pi.id or n.match_data_id = pi.id)
and n.match_mode = '1'
and n.match_gene_type = '1'
and n.notification_status = '2'
and pi.id_card_no IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

use window function `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select pi.id                 pid,
   n.id                  nid,
   n.match_mode,
   n.match_method,
   n.match_gene_type,
   n.notification_status,
   pi.person_name,
   pi.id_card_no,
   pi.race,
   row_number() over(partition by pi.id order by pi.id) as rn
from notification n, person_info pi
where (n.src_data_id = pi.id or n.match_data_id = pi.id)
and n.match_mode = '1'
and n.match_gene_type = '1'
and n.notification_status = '2'
and pi.id_card_no IS NOT NULL
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care which row do you get you can get the `MAX()` value of each column.

```
select pi.id                 pid,
   MAX(n.id)                  nid,
   MAX(n.match_mode),
   MAX(n.match_method),
   MAX(n.match_gene_type),
   MAX(n.notification_status),
   MAX(pi.person_name),
   MAX(pi.id_card_no),
   MAX(pi.race)
from notification n, person_info pi
where (n.src_data_id = pi.id or n.match_data_id = pi.id)
and n.match_mode = '1'
and n.match_gene_type = '1'
and n.notification_status = '2'
and pi.id_card_no IS NOT NULL
group by pi.id
```